# How to add an image in an <li> tag in a registered menu on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have just learnt how to create a nav menu using wordpress functions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

My original menu looks like this:

```
<ul class="menu"> <!-- First Menu -->
    <li> <a href="#"> Clients </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> About Us </a> </li>
    <li class="contact"> Contact </li>
    <li class="hasImage"> <a href="*link to the homepage**"> <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/images/logo.png" class="logo"> </a> </li>
</ul>
```

The last `<li>` tag (which has a class .hasImage) contains an image (which has class .logo) and shows up in all s.
How do I add the image in the `<li>`? Is there a way to make every primary menu have this extra `<li>` with the image ?

functions.php:

```
// Registering the Primary Menu

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'primary-menu', __( 'Primary Menu' ) );
}
```

and on my page template:

```
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) );
```

** The only thing I can solve here is to add a class to the list item in the administrator panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how you can programmatically add an `<li>` to a menu that you've registered, this should work:

In your page template:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
    'items_wrap'=>'<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s<li class="hasImage">YOUR IMAGE HTML GOES HERE</li></ul>'
));
```

Comment: What are these variables? 
`<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s`

Comment: That is the string that wordpress parses by default when creating the menu.  You can alter that string to create menus that aren't html lists.  From the wordpress documentation `%1$s is expanded to the value of the 'menu_id' parameter, %2$s is expanded to the value of the 'menu_class' parameter, and %3$s is expanded to the value of the list items`...http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu